# Searching for an answer why the answer in the book is not equal to the answer I receive from my program

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Volumeofatriangle {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Create a scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        //Receive the length of sides of a triangle.
        System.out.print("Enter the length of your triangle: ");
        double lengthOfSides = input.nextDouble();
            
        //area of triangle.
        double areaOfTriangle = lengthOfSides * lengthOfSides * Math.sqrt(3) / 4;
            
        //volume of triangle.
        double volumeOfTriangle = areaOfTriangle * lengthOfSides;
            
        System.out.println("The triangle has an area of " + areaOfTriangle +
            "and a volume of " + volumeOfTriangle);
    }
}
```

At the moment I fill in 3,5 as triangle the area I will get the following answers:

> The triangle has an area of 5.304405598179686and a volume of 18.565419593628903

The exercise in the book is:

> (Compute the volume of a triangle) Write a program that reads in the length of sides of an equilateral triangle and computes the area and volume using the following formulas:
>
> `area = square root 3/4 (length of sides)till the power of 2.`
> `volume = area * length.`

With this information I made the program above. However the answer in the book to a 3.5 equiliteral triangle:

> The area is 3.89
> The volume of the triangular prism is 19.48

I tried writing the program several times but every time I don't get the answer from the book.

Did I make a mistake or is the answer in the book wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried to do calculations on paper to verify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer in the book is wrong. If you do it by hand, your program's results are the correct ones: `3.5^2*sqrt(3)/4 = 5.3`.

Comment: I assume it's the solution of an older version of the question with different parameters.

Comment: That makes sense, ~3.89 is the answer if side lengths are 3.

Comment: Thank you indeed if I fill in 3 it gives 3,89, however the Triangular prism displays 19.48.... makes no sense I think.

Why did my answer receive -1? I tried to do all right here?

Comment: The message is clear, I kept trying when it failed the first time.
And I tried to use the best english I can.

Only thing is it is maybe only useful to me. 
But how can if possibly be useful to everyone I mean everyone encounters different problems while programming, so I don't understand why I only get downvoted?

Comment: @VincentNelissen I didn't vote you down? I don't have enough reputation for that

Comment: @EFM oh I'm sorry my apoligies.

Answer (score 1):

Actually answer is true, but the descriptions are not clear. The book is writing for the question "Enter length of the sides and height of the Equilateral triangle:", it means you should enter length and height(2 different value).

According to the book, it must be 3 and 5. (Just point is not necessary, between 3 and 5 at the book).

Already normally you should plus with "height" to find The volume of the Triangular prism. So the formula is: volume = area * height(writing length instead of height, confusing)

So results are, area = 3.89 and volume = 19.48(like the book, just more digits after the point at my result)

I made the code like that:

---

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        double area;
        System.out.println("Enter length of sides and height of the Equilateral triangle: ");
        double lengthOfSides = input.nextDouble();
        double height = input.nextDouble();

        area = (Math.sqrt(3)/4)*Math.pow(lengthOfSides, 2);
        double volume = area * height;

        System.out.println("The area is " + area);
        System.out.print("The volume of the Triangular prism is " + volume);
```

---

(I am talking about Introduction to Java, Daniel Liang, Eleventh Edition, Page 91)